# OSX Automator - open app in application contents folder?

Tags: mac, bash, automator

I would like to achieve the following via Mac's Automator:

- open /Applications/Microsoft\ Outlook.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Outlook\ Profile\ Manager.app
- wait for me to select an outlook profile and then close the "Outlook Profile Manager.app".
- upon closing of the "Outlook Profile Manager.app" application, launch /Applications/Microsoft\ Outlook.app

The problem I have with Automator is that I am unable to address the Outlook Profile Manager app since its technically an "app inside an app", which seems not supported.

Anyway way around this? Thank you

Comment: Can you manually run this profile manger without Outlook running? I'd suspect one relies on the other.

Comment: Yes, you can run the profile manager app no matter if outlook is open or not, the change just takes effect after outlook is restarted. I just want to create a shell script that allowed me to choose the profile I want, and then start outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following **AppleScript** code will launch **Outlook Profile Manager.app** then lets you choose the desired **profile** from a list, selects your chosen list item, quits **Outlook Profile Manager.app** , and activates **Outlook.app**

You can add a **Run AppleScript** command to your **Automator workflow** and insert this following **AppleScript**, or run it in **Script Editor.app**.

*Tested using macOS Big Sur.*

```
tell application id "com.microsoft.outlook.profilemanager" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "Outlook Profile Manager"
        set frontmost to true
        repeat until exists of group 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        set theProfiles to get value of text field 1 of rows of ¬
            table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1
        tell current application
            activate
            set chosenProfile to (choose from list theProfiles with title ¬
                "Choose Profile" with prompt "Choose Profile" OK button name ¬
                "OK" cancel button name "Cancel") as text
            if chosenProfile = "false" then
                tell application id "com.microsoft.outlook.profilemanager" to quit
                return
            end if
            set theCount to 1
            repeat with i from 1 to count of theProfiles
                set thisItem to item i of theProfiles
                if thisItem = chosenProfile then
                    exit repeat
                else
                    set theCount to theCount + 1
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
        set frontmost to true
        repeat until exists of group 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        set selected of row theCount of table 1 of scroll area 1 ¬
            of group 1 of window 1 to true
        click menu button 1 of group 1 of window 1
        click menu item "Set as Default" of menu 1 of ¬
            menu button 1 of group 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell

tell application id "com.microsoft.outlook.profilemanager" to quit
repeat while application id "com.microsoft.outlook.profilemanager" is running
    delay 0.1
end repeat
tell application id "com.microsoft.Outlook" to activate
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you so very much for this. I am sure you just made the lives of thousands of Outlook for MAC users easier!